# Easiest way to retrieve rows from a table with at least one value in NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

Working with MSSSQL I have a table with more than 20 columns, and I want to retrieve rows which have at least one of the column values in NULL. Which would be the most efficient way, or do you have to write something like this?:

```
Select * from tableName where col1 is null or col2 is null or col3 is null....
```

Thank you!

Comment: if they're all the same type (ex. varchar) you could do `where col1 + col2 + col3 + ect is null` but yes you will have to check all values somehow

Comment: Thank you @JamieD77, the values are of different kind

Comment: You could chain multiple `COALESCE` like `COALESCE(col1, COALESCE(col2, COALESCE(col3,col4)))  IS NULL` but not sure if that will be more efficient

Comment: If you don't have to do it Dynamically (meaning that you will always know the number/names of columns) then your approach is best to list all columns specifically.  However, if you need this to work on any number of columns then create a Loop of all of the columns in the tables columns.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9494/in-sql-server-2008-how-can-i-get-all-the-columns-that-are-marked-as-nullable-in.   This article should help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that SQL Server will need to check each column in each row to make the determination (at least until it finds a `NULL` value in a given column). That means that it's going to be doing a full table scan no matter how you happen to organize your query. So, while there may be "prettier" ways to do your query, when it comes to performance I doubt that you'll find anything that is going to be quicker.

The calculated column that @Denis suggested is an exception, but that's because SQL Server is effectively doing the same work ahead of time (or even a little more work, because now it has to write out to the persisted index). At that point it's a matter of where the performance hit is most important to you - finding these columns, or every time that you write to the table.

Comment: In theory, you don't have to check each column in each row, as soon as you find a null in a row, you can stop checking that row.  So, any method that doesn't check all columns every time, is an improvement over the listed COALESCE method, other issues asid.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said, "at least until it finds a NULL value in the given column". You are correct to point out that the `COALESCE` solutions (if they worked, which they won't) would end up breaking the short-circuit that an `OR` condition would otherwise provide.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to pre-calculate these values (persisted calculated column) (if this appropriate for your case), then index them and query. Here is the idea behind:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    col1 int,
    col2 int,
    col3 int,
    col_calculated AS CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL OR col2 IS NULL OR col3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END PERSISTED
);

CREATE INDEX IX_TEMP_COLCALCULATED ON #temp(col_calculated);

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(1, 2, 3), (5, 6, NULL);

SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE col_calculated = 0;
```